# How to get the UDID in iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, udid

I want to get the device id and send it into a web service. How can I get the `UDID` in iOS 6

Thanks

Comment: Try this http://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/how-to-detect-ios-device-udid-name-version-model-by-programmatically/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

UDID is no longer available in iOS 6+ due to security / privacy reasons. Instead, use `identifierForVendor` or `advertisingIdentifier`.

### identifierForVendor:

> An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s
>   vendor. (read-only)
>
> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the
>   same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned
>   for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for
>   apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

### advertisingIdentifier:

> An alphanumeric string unique to each device, used only for serving
>   advertisements. (read-only)
>
> Unlike the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice, the same value is
>   returned to all vendors. This identifier may change—for example, if
>   the user erases the device—so you should not cache it.

[This](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/09/udid-apis-in-ios-6/) post explains it well.

Also, see Apple's documentation for the [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49) and [`advertisingIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012654-CH1-SW4).

Comment: then how to get device id for uniquely identification

Comment: I edited it. You'd use the "identifierForVendor" or the "advertisingIdentifier"

Comment: For adhoc testers, they need to be able to find their UDID so I can them to the profile.  It's a pain that you can no long see the UDID from the phone. So many people no longer connect their devices to iTunes.

Comment: @RogerGilbrat I don't know if something changed since this post but my adhoc testers running iOS 6 get their UDID using apps on the store (such as UDID Tool)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID):

> OpenUDID is a drop-in replacement for the deprecated uniqueIdentifier property of the UIDevice class on iOS (a.k.a. UDID) and otherwise is an industry-friendly equivalent for iOS and Android, and most recently Windows C# and Silverlight (see links above).

**Edit: Make sure since May 1st 2013 for iOS 6 to use the [this](https://github.com/xaviermichel/OpenUDID) Branch until the Main is updated:**