# How to get application installation time in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, installation

Is there any way to get application insatllation time in iPhone? I wanted to use this information as a unique identifier, can I use it for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. You don't know anything about the actual installation (duration / time) within your app. You only know the first start date.

For unique IDs, check this answer:
[How to get the UDID in iOS 6 and iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456996/how-to-get-the-udid-in-ios-6)

Comment: There is restriction on using UDID by apple na, we can not use it and I have provide support for my app from iOS 4.3, so I guess I cann't use UUID also. Thinking about MAC adress as an alternative.

Comment: That's why I posted a link showing alternatives... only the `uniqueIdentifier` call is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to get the application installation time.. You can keep track of the first launch of your application ***within your application*** using **NSUserDefault**.

In **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** you could do

```
NSDate *date =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"FirstLaunchTime"];
if (date == nil) {
     // nil means your application running for the first time
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"FirstLaunchTime"]; // set the current time
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is check the /Documents directory to see if there's anything it when it is first run (there shouldn't be if it's the first time it's been installed on that device). If not, write a file there with the current time stamp.

I guess you could use this information as a unique identifier, but in theory, there could be multiple people who open the app for the first time, at the same time. I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a field in user setting for this and when user installs and opens it you will get a callback in appDelegate's didFinishLaunching method.

Here you can check if the particular field is nil then only store current date time. You can use this date time in your app.