# Get UDID Programmatically for iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I got one solution

```
NSString *uid;
uid= [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
NSLog(@"udid is %@",uid);
```

But it shows me "uniqueIdentifier" is deprecated and it's available in iOS 5. How can I get UDID programmatically for iOS 6?

Answer (score 2):

UDID is no longer available in iOS 6+ due to security / privacy reasons. Instead, use [identifierForVendor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49) or advertisingIdentifier.

here is the link
[How to get the UDID in iOS 6 and iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456996/how-to-get-the-udid-in-ios-6)