# get UDID of IOS device programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, udid

I want to get UDID of iOS device programmatically. I am using the following code to get UDID of iOS  device.

```
NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
NSString *uuidString = uuid.UUIDString;
```

But output I get is different from actual UDID of my device.

Comment: I think you can find what you're looking for in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456996/how-to-get-the-udid-in-ios-6-and-ios-7

Comment: What made you think that would give you your UDID? Just a random hope, plucked from thin air?

Comment: @Tommy well there is a very small chance that it could be the right one. LOL!

Comment: @Fogmeister, it's not even very small, it's equal to zero, actually) That's why it's called UUID. Not just a random number generator :)

Comment: @FreeNickname yeah, but there is still a chance. Just read... If you generate 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years then there is a 50% chance that there is one duplicate in the list. LOL!

Comment: @Fogmeister, There is a [magnificent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705008/simple-proof-that-guid-is-not-unique) devoted to this topic :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
NSString* identifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]; // IOS 6+
NSLog(@"output is : %@", identifier);
```

**Swift 2.X (HERE X DENOTE ABOVE ALL VERSION FROM 2.0)**

```
let identifier: String = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor().UUIDString()
NSLog("output is : %@", identifier)
```

**Swift3**

```
let identifier = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString

NSLog("output is : %@", identifier! as String)
```

additional [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352418/how-to-generate-uuid-in-ios)

> Apple is apparently starting to remove access to the UDID (Unique Device IDentifier) in iOS5. In any event, the best you can now do for identification purposes is to use a UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier). This has to be on a per-app basis. That is, there is no way to identify the device any longer, but you can identify an app on a device.As long as the user doesn’t completely delete the app, then this identifier will persist between app launches, and at least let you identify the same user using a particular app on a device. Unfortunately, if the user completely deletes and then reinstalls the app then the ID will change, but this is the best anyone can do going forward.

Comment: Technically this is what Apple will now allow you to do instead of using the UDID, with the caveat that you're not allowed to use that identifier for serving advertisements. But +1 because this is what people now do for anything else that used to use the UDID.

Comment: I have used this code. But it does not return me the same UDID as of my iOS device. Is there any way to get the actual UDID of my device?

Comment: Is this identifier is unique for all devices and apps?

Comment: @NishiBansalas multiple people have stated. No, it is not possible. A quick google search will show you this. If you had searched SO before posting you would have found this. You can browse the Apple developer site to also read this. Not sure how much more confirmation you want? The UDID is not available.

Comment: Can I get Any other unique id associated to my device to authenticate with my app?

Comment: @NishiBansal read any of the answers to your question. They have all provided the `identifierForVendor` code.

Comment: Yes I got that. But I am doubtful about that is this identifierForVendor unique for every device and app if my provisioning profile and certificates are same for different apps?

Comment: ya  its unique it identifiey your device ,but if you delete and reinstall the app the ID wii change , but it mean the same device'

Comment: Casting a string `as String` it is pointless. Use a `??` nil coalescing operator `let identifier =  UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? ""` or use `if let` / `guard` to unwrap your optionals

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I need a UDID not UUID, Do you know any way for that?