# Identifier for Vendor is gettnig changed everyTime app is reinstalled

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uuid

I have created a function to get UUID

```
func deviceUUID() -> String {
    return UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString ?? ""
}
```

But the problem is that when ever I uninstall the app from same device and re-install it. I am getting a totally new UUIDString. If this the default behaviour then can I get previous UUID somehow ? because I have UUID as user ID in our server.

I do have a solution in my mind but I do not know that will it work or not so please guide me on this.

Lets say I get the ID first time and save it in keychains. When user reinstall the app I get the ID from keychains. Is this possible ?

Comment: UUID is not a static , see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652359/get-udid-of-ios-device-programmatically/31652454#31652454

Comment: if you need the previous ID then stored in Userdefaults

Comment: User defaults are deleted when the app is un installed I think so.

Comment: there is no other way my brother , for secure purpose apple did this , then stored in keychain archiver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This correct behavior as described in [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) documentation.

If you want to store some identifier that is persisted when the app is uninstalled you should save a unique value in the keychain.

Just be aware that even these will not be 100% stored, the user can delete then if he/she has knowledge of the keychain or the device is wiped.

Comment: You can use apple API for unique token generateToken(completionHandler:) . NOTE - The app you use to generate the token must be associated with your developer account; otherwise, the generation request fails