# What other information can be retrieved without asking for permission from the users in iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I came to know that we can not use the device id, IMEI or UDID, so is there any other way around to identify the device uniquely and what other information can be retrieved without asking for permission, like public information. I came to know last played song can be retrieved, if yes then how.

Comment: Identify user/device: Has been asked many time, please google. About all the other information: Too broad question, which again you can find by searching.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get UDID of IOS device programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652359/get-udid-of-ios-device-programmatically)

Comment: This is not about how to get the UDID. This problem asks for the details which can get without asking for user permission like iTunes playlist.

Answer (score 1):

To uniquely identify iOS devices you can use this:
[OpenUDID](https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID)

```
[OpenUDID value]
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks lot , that provide unique id for each device well answer

Comment: I was not asking about the unique values, I was asking about the different things we can get from ios without seeking user permission like iTunes playlist.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the link proposed by NaGib ToroNgo you'll see that Apple is giving you an option to identify the device, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor?language=objc), which you can get by using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
```

However, as noted by Apple, if you're planning on serving advertisements using the identifier, you'll have to use the `advertisingIdentifier` property of the `ASIdentifierManager` class instead!